# Insert link in String field if substring matches

Tags: grails

I have a "comments" String field in my domain. On each save or update of the field I want to check if the field contains a sub string that matches a String from another field of the same domain (or different domain for that matter). I need to run through all the instances of that field to see if there is a match. If it matches I want to transform it into a link inside the comments field to a show action for that entry matching the sub string.

So for example, a comments field for a product with a serial number would note if the product has been replaced by another one by giving it's serial number in the comments field. Like: "This product was replaced by SN1234". I want to automatically transform SN1234 into a link to show the product with serial number SN1234.

What is the best way to go about this ? In the controller, in the GSP ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the column you're trying to match on is indexed, you'll just need to do a query for the match and if found, modify your comment to include the URL.  Controller or Service doesn't really matter for the lookup (although I would probably put it in a service).  You'll want to be sure the search is not transactional so it will be as fast as it can be.  No way I would do any of this in a GSP.

To insert the link, you could a simple find and replace.  Once you know which text you want turned into the link, pseudo code follows:

```
def comment = "This product was replaced by SN1234" 
def match = "SN1234"
def link = g.link(action: "show", controller: "product", id: "${product.id}", match)
comment = comment.replace(match, link)
```

Which you would then end up with

```
"This product was replaced by <a href='/product/1234'>SN1234</a>"
```

There may be more efficient ways to do this, but this is a good place to start.

Comment: How do I insert the link tag in to the String field ?

Comment: Thx! Uhm... the link just shows up us a string in the field. How can I make it a real link ?

Comment: It also dosen't work with a <g:fieldValue /> tag. Any way to make this work ? Some other tag maybe ?

Comment: No tag necessary.  Just put it in a div or something.  <div>${comment}</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) to do it in your domain. So whenever the domain is inserted/updated you can check that your field has been changed. Then you can insert your link.

```
def beforeInsert() {
    yourMethod()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('yourField')) {
        yourMethod()
    }
}
```